# Attempt to compare nil with number Error in Lua (Corona Lab)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm completely new to the Corona (Lua). After running the game, the game seems to work perfectly, until a few seconds later when I get the following error: 'Attempt to compare nil with number'

local function gameLoop()

```
-- create new asteroids
createAsteroid()

-- remove asteroids which have been drifted off the screen
for i = #asteroidsTable, 1, -1 do
    local thisAsteroid = asteroidsTable [i]

    if (thisAsteroid.x < -100 or
        thisAsteroid.x > display.contentWidth  + 100 or
        thisAsteroid.y < -100 or
        thisAsteroid.y > display.contentHeight + 100 )

    then 

        display.remove( thisAsteroid )
        table.remove( asteroidsTable)

    end

end
```

end

---

As you can see above, 'thisAsteroid' is in the 'asteroidsTable = {}' which is defined as a variable in top of the module and OUTSIDE of any function.

local asteroidsTable = { }

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try using `print` statements before the line where error is encountered.

Comment: can you please be more specific and give an example of the print statement? (sorry, I'm new to coding)

Answer (score 0):

Either `thisAsteroid.x`, `thisAsteroid.y`, `display.contentWidth` or `display.contentHeight` is `nil`.

use `print(thisAsteroid.x)` etc to find out which one is `nil`.

You should also get a line number with with the error message that helps you find the problem.

Once you have found the `nil` value you either have to prevent it from becoming `nil` or if you can't do that you should restrict your comparison to non-`nil` values.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
-- create new asteroids
createAsteroid()

-- remove asteroids which have been drifted off the screen
for i = #asteroidsTable, 1, -1 do
    local asteroid = asteroidsTable [i]

    if (asteroid.x < -100 or
        asteroid.x > display.contentWidth  + 100 or
        asteroid.y < -100 or
        asteroid.y > display.contentHeight + 100 )

    then 
        local asteroidToRemove = table.remove(asteroidsTable, i)
        if asteroidToRemove ~= nil then
            display.remove(asteroidToRemove)
            asteroidToRemove= nil
        end
    end
end
end
```

From lua.org [documentation](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.remove)

> table.remove (list [, pos])
>
> Removes from list the element at position pos, returning the value of
>   the removed element. When pos is an integer between 1 and #list, it
>   shifts down the elements list[pos+1], list[pos+2], ···, list[#list]
>   and erases element list[#list]; The index pos can also be 0 when #list
>   is 0, or #list + 1; in those cases, the function erases the element
>   list[pos].
>
> The default value for pos is #list, so that a call table.remove(l) removes the last element of list l

So with instruction `table.remove(asteroidsTable)` you remove last element from table `asteroidsTable` but you should remove the i-th element.

Read more about removing elements from table from Corona [forum](https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/34186-removing-display-object-from-table/).